# How to set default date on a field of a Postgres table?

Tags: postgresql, timestamp

**How to add default date on postgresql?**

I tried `getdate()` but the command gives a error:

```
ERROR: function getdate() does not exist
SQL state: 42883
Hint: No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

The command issued was:

```
Create TABLE CREATE_ORDERS (
Plot_ID VARCHAR (50) ,
USER_ID VARCHAR(50),
ORDER_ID VARCHAR(50),
TOTAL_AMOUNT float NOT NULL DEFAULT 0.000,
DOWNPAYMENT float NOT NULL DEFAULT 25000,
BALANCE_INSTALLMENT_AMOUNT float NOT NULL DEFAULT 0.000,
NO_OF_INSTALLMENTS float NOT NULL DEFAULT 12,
PURCHASE_DATE TIMESTAMP  NOT NULL DEFAULT GETDATE(),
DUE_DATE TIMESTAMP  NOT NULL DEFAULT GETDATE(),
CONSTRAINT AK_TransactionID1 UNIQUE(PLOT_ID),
CONSTRAINT AK_TransactionID2 UNIQUE(ORDER_ID),
PRIMARY KEY (PLOT_ID, ORDER_ID));
```

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/functions-datetime.html

Comment: Where in the manual did you find `getdate()`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use keyword `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` instead of function `GETDATE()`.

```
--Current date and time    
SELECT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;

--Current date    
SELECT CURRENT_DATE;

--Current date and time    
SELECT NOW();
```

More info [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-datetime.html).

Answer (score 2):

`current_date` function returns current date.

Check https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-datetime.html and https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-CURRENT for more details.